# Incorrect page numbers in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

I am using `tocbibind` to get Acknowledgements, Declaration and Intro into ToC. The problem is, page numbers are incorrect. I have also tried adding them by `\addcontentsline`, it stays the same. ToC shows Acknowl and Decl, both at p.2 and Intro at p.4 whereas Acknowl is at page 1 and Decl at page 2 and Intro at page 5. It gives correct page numbers for the rest of the document (Including Index and Bib). I am also using `fancyhdr`, `titlesec`, `idxlayout`, if they have any effect on this problem.
Ideally I want page numbers to start from Title page (I have tried `\setcounter{page}{1}` within title but doesn't seem to work) and also the printed page numbers must start from ToC page. At the moment numbering starts and shows from Acnowl page. Here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}  
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}  

\begin{document}  

\title{NAME}  
\setcounter{page}{1}  
\maketitle  

\chapter*{Acknowledgments}  
\chapter*{Declaration}  

\tableofcontents  

\chapter*{Introduction}  
\chapter{First}  

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not see a problem with your MWE. The first chapter is on page 5, the same page number as the entry in the table of contents.

You mentioned `\addcontentsline`. If the command gets on the previous page, then also
the page number is taken from the previous page. Make sure that `\addcontentsline` is on the right page, e.g.:

```
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgments}
\chapter*{Acknowledgments}
```

or

```
\chapter*{Acknowledgments}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgments}
```

Comment: In fact I was trying to make "tocbibind" to work, but it didn't. Your suggestion has solved the problem though (of incorrect page numbering of Acknwl, Declaration etc in the ToC). I also wanted to start the page numbers from title page, but for now I can work without it. Thanks very much.